# HP Smart Array p410i rebuild percentage not correctly working

Tags: storage, hp, hp-proliant, hardware-raid, hp-smart-array

I have a HP Poliant with a p410i and when I rebuild my raid 5 with a quick remove and insert to test the rebuild percentage goes up to 10% and then jumps to 92%.  I continues up to 100% and the Array configuration utility still says rebuilding for a bit 5 - 10 minutes then it stops and then Parity initialization starts.  Wondering if this is the correct process for rebuild.
Any comments would be appreciated.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. One of my concerns though is the rebuilding % the Array Configuration Utility reflects. The percentage climbs by single digit increments till it reaches 10% and then jumps to 92%. I guess I wasn't clear I should have asked is this jump normal behavior as I have seen others go up by single increments.

Answer (score 2):

The rebuild process is automatic on these controllers, so you do not need to take any additional action. The background parity initialization occurs when the array is created, so you'll probably see that for several hours after initial installation.

From the [Smart Array technology manual](http://h20000.www2.hp.com/bc/docs/support/SupportManual/c00687518/c00687518.pdf).

> Background RAID creation 
>   When a RAID 1, RAID 5, or RAID 6 logical drive is first created, the Smart Array controller must build 
>   the logical drive within the array before enabling certain advanced performance techniques. While 
>   the logical drive is created, the storage volume is accessible by the host with full fault tolerance. The 
>   Smart Array controller creates the logical drive whenever the controller is not busy; this is called 
>   background parity initialization. Parity initialization takes several hours to complete, depending on 
>   the size of the logical drive and how busy the host keeps the controller. Before parity initialization 
>   completes, normal writes to RAID 5 and RAID 6 logical drives are slower because the controller must 
>   read the entire stripe to update the parity data and maintain fault tolerance. These writes during 
>   parity initialization are called regenerative writes or reconstructed writes.